# CMD on Windows echo variable value from text line

Tags: string, variables, cmd, find, echo

I have a txt text file and I would like to generate the number value of a variable inside

The structure of the text file is this:

```
[Parsed_mpdecimate_0 @ 00000270d861c680] 875> = hi keep pts: 142000 pts_time: 8.875 drop_count: -2
[Parsed_mpdecimate_0 @ 00000270d861c680] keep pts: 142667 pts_time: 8.91669 drop_count: -3
[Parsed_mpdecimate_0 @ 00000270d861c680] keep pts: 143333 pts_time: 8.95831 drop_count: -4
[Parsed_mpdecimate_0 @ 00000270d861c680] 783> = hi keep pts: 144000 pts_time: 9 drop_count: -5
Etc....
```

How do I generate the "pts_time" variable number? and print a list on screen

I know that in windows 10 there is the AWK command, how should I do?

Comment: I do not know that there is an `awk` in Windows 10. Please copy and paste as text the code you are trying to make work. SO is not a free, bespoke script writing service. Please provide an MRE (Minimal Reproducible Example) in accordance with https://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: I'm going to assume that this is the output from an `ffmpeg` command, and my best guess is that you're wanting to parse it, to output the following only: `pts_time: 8.875`, `pts_time: 8.91669`, `pts_time: 8.95831`, `pts_time: 9`, or `8.875`, `8.91669`, `8.95831`, `9`. Can you please clarify when you [edit] your question to submit the code you are having an issue with.

Comment: That's right, it's an output generated with ffmpeg. I would like to read one line at a time and extract the pts_time parameters.

I have to display these parameters on the screen

It should be some function on the strings

Answer (score 0):

Here's one relatively slow way, *(just change `C:\Users\felikszed\Desktop\ffmpegOutput.txt` to the fullpath to your text file)*:

```cmd
For /F "Delims=" %G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R "^\[Parsed_mpdecimate_.*pts_time:" "C:\Users\felikszed\Desktop\ffmpegOutput.txt"') Do @Set "}=%G" & For /F %H In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /V /D /C "Echo(!}:*pts_time:=!"') Do @Echo %H
```

---

**[EDIT /]**

Based upon your comment, if you want to run this in a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), you should have used the appropriate tag, and I'd have included the solution for that too.

Here it is:

```batch-file
@Echo Off & SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R
 "^\[Parsed_mpdecimate_.*pts_time:" "C:\Users\felikszed\Desktop\ffmpegOutput.txt"'
) Do (Set "}=%%G" & SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    Echo(!}:*pts_time:=!& EndLocal)
Pause
```

Comment: Compo, you helped me, your solution is the best, it works

i can't put the code in a .bat file, but it works fine anyway

thank you so much

Comment: @felikszed, I provided an answer for the title CMD on Windows, and the [[tag:cmd]] tag. You did not mention batch files in your question title, body, or tags. If you want it to work in a batch file there are some required modifications.

Comment: I have added the [[tag:batch-file]] version for you.